# IOS Memory is not freed Uinsg NSURLConnection to download Youtube HTML data

Tags: ios, youtube, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to download the HTML for the youtube url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8SPr6eIVKE
here is my code...

```
 url = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8SPr6eIVKE";
```

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

```
[request setValue:(NSString *)kUserAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
      //My code goes here

     });
 }];
```

The problem, is that this NSData is leaking memory. This works perfectly If I try to download an image, but some kind of leak is happening if I try to download HTML data. Here is more info for the leak.

1 CoreFoundation __CFDataGrow
2 CoreFoundation CFDataReplaceBytes
3 CoreFoundation CFDataAppendBytes
4 CFNetwork gzipDecodeData(z_stream_s, unsigned char, __CFAllocator const, __CFData const*, int)
5 CFNetwork GZipDataDecoder::decodeData(CFAllocator const, __CFData const, unsigned char)
6 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::decodedDecoding(unsigned char, unsigned char const, lon

So friends any clue?  I am trying to play a youtube video without UIWebView...(Don't know whether apple will approve)

Comment: This 'queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]' appears quite odd - are you making this call from within a NSOperation? What I would have expected is that you create a queue, save a reference in an ivar/property, then supply that value for 'queue:'. Also I don't think Apple cares all that much how you show the video.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the reply, I found out that the memory was leaking due to the cache..I fixed it Have a nice dat